# Getting undefined reference to std::thread::_M_start_thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, ld, undefined-reference

I'm building an app that uses a 3rd party lib (Box2D-MT) which I build from sources. When linking, I get this undefined reference error:

```
b2Threading.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IM12b2ThreadPoolFviEJPS1_iEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IM12b2ThreadPoolFviEJPS1_iEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0xa4): 
undefined reference to 'std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)())'
```

I am building with g++ and link with

```
-lBox2D -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lstdc++
```

also, I am compiling with

```
-std=c++11
```

looking into libstdc++.a I can see a similar this symbol exists (it's "T"):

```
nm -C /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.2/libstdc++.a | grep _M_start_thread
0000000000000000 T std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>)
```

but this overload doesn't take a second parameter.

I've searched all the internet for something similar, but no one seems to have had this issue before (in any context).

Any hint on why I get this error and how I could solve it?

Comment: Use the `-pthread` compiler flag instead of `-lpthread`. Use it for compiling and linking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ tried that right now, I get exactly the same error

Comment: What is your **full**
 link command?

Comment: @n.m. g++ -L./3rdparty/easyunit/ -o "foo"  objects.o -leasyunit -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpng -lBox2D -lrt -lpthread -ldl

Comment: I changed the libs in different order but getting the same result

Comment: I mentioned use `-ptthread` for compiling **and** linking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did, but then I changed it back since there was no difference (got the same error). What is the technical diff between the two?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a headers/libraries version mismatch. This is what I've got:

```
$ nm -C /pkgs/gcc/4.9.2/lib/libstdc++.a | grep std::thread::_M_start_thread
00000000 T std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>)

$ nm -C /pkgs/gcc/5.2.0/lib/libstdc++.a | grep std::thread::_M_start_thread
00000000 T std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>)
00000000 T std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)())

$ fgrep -r M_start_thread /usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.9.2/include/
/pkgs/gcc/4.9.2/include/c++/4.9.2/thread:        _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
/pkgs/gcc/4.9.2/include/c++/4.9.2/thread:    _M_start_thread(__shared_base_type);

$ fgrep -r M_start_thread /usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/5.2.0/include/
/pkgs/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:        _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
/pkgs/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:        _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
/pkgs/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:    _M_start_thread(__shared_base_type, void (*)());
/pkgs/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:    _M_start_thread(__shared_base_type);
```

Comment: ok, this could be the case. I suppose when I build Box2D it uses some different headers/libraries than when I build my app which links to it.
How can I tell which ones it uses, and how can I control it? This might be specific to the build system it uses (cmake) but maybe there's some more general solution (like removing all but one version of headers/libs from system?)

Comment: I checked the system, I only have 4.9.2 include files and 4.8 and 4.9 libs. Neither libs contain the needed overload. How is it possible that the headers contain a reference to it if it's not in the libs?