# C++: undefined reference to std::thread while compiling opencv and tensorflow with g++

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, g++, libpng

I want to perform some preprocessing, with opencv, on an image which will be fed to a tensorflow model.
The preprocessing part reads in a `.png` file, the code works as a standalone program, but I want to use it inside the program that runs the tensorflow model, so I generated an object file as below. The program for preprocessing works perfectly as standalone.

```
g++ -std=c++11 preProcess.cpp -I/home/dpk/anaconda2/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/home/dpk/anaconda2/lib -lpng16 -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -c
```

The tensorflow program, `Inference.cc` was compiled as below

```
g++ -std=c++11 preProcess.o Inference.cc -I/home/dpk/anaconda2/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/local/include/tf -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -I/usr/local/include/tf/bazel-genfiles -g -Wall -D_DEBUG -Wshadow -Wno-sign-compare -w  -L/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc -L/home/dpk/anaconda2/lib -lpng16 -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf` -ltensorflow_cc -o inference
```

This throws the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `std::thread::_State::~_State()@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::thread::_State@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
```

This error seems to be caused by linking `-L/home/dpk/anaconda2/lib`, because compilation goes smoothly when I don't link that folder , but then the program fails to read `.png` files. Hence it appears that, that folder is necessary for handling `.png`.

I need my program to read `.png` files as well as run the tensorflow model. How can I make both of them work?

Comment: It seems to be part of the C++11 standard. Try using the flag  `-std=c++11`

Comment: @bracco23 Tried that, throws the same error. I'll edit my question to include that flag

Comment: Might look silly, but check if you have the header `#include <thread>` in your file.

Comment: @TheApache Thanks for the suggestion, that didn't help either, got the same error.

Comment: Try passing `-lstdc++` to the linker, so it links to the standard library.

Comment: @tambre Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately,  I get the same error with `-lstdc++`

Comment: For me, it sounds like `libtensorflow_cc.so` is built for another version of standard C++ library than you have currently installed and link to your application. Btw. I found a similar question: [SO: Getting undefined reference to std::thread::_M_start_thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38226993/7478597) (though the answer was not accepted). You could check this using the "How to" I found in [SO: How do you find what version of libstdc++ library is installed on your linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10354636/7478597).

Comment: This happened to me because my $PATH was pointing to an old version of gcc. `which gcc` told me that.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is built with gcc 6 because there is a linker bug which prevents the successful compilation with gcc 5. You must build and link your program with gcc 6 to avoid this linker error.