# Benchmark undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, pthreads, google-benchmark

I want to use Google Benchmark, for that I have a simple test written in main.cpp file. to build my project I have a CMake file as follow:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

find_library(BENCHMARK_LIBRARY NAMES benchmark HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/externals/lib")
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

# benchmark binary
add_executable(benchmark main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(benchmark ${BENCHMARK_LIBRARY} Threads::Threads)
```

But every time I run "make" it gives me the error:

```
In function `benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks(benchmark::BenchmarkReporter*, 
benchmark::BenchmarkReporter*)':
benchmark.cc:(.text+0x214b): undefined reference to `std::thread
::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, 
std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())'
```

What am I doing wrong? I just started working with CMake so I don't have a lot of knowledge. I searched but couldn't get a solution.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question in order to provide the exact `cmake` invocation along with the link step command line (e.g. the `ld` invocation)?

Answer (score 1):

Observation: this is a linker error, the code compiled fine, but a symbol was not found when the linker tried to combine all the objects and libraries into an executable.

[Getting undefined reference to std::thread::_M_start_thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226993/getting-undefined-reference-to-stdthread-m-start-thread) <- related question

You probably have multiple compiler/library versions installed and are compiling with newer c++ headers and linking against an older c++ library.

Comment: I was running my program on physical machine. When I ran it in the docker it worked fine. I guess It was some older library bug. Thanks for your response.